# StartService returns ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: c++, driver, wdk

I'm working with driver creation using Windows Driver Kit 8.
I created a simple project in Visual Studio 2012 with default code for a KMDF driver. The driver was compiled without errors.
Next I tried to install it using [Kmdmanager](http://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/downloads/All%20Points%20Bulletin%20Hacks/146/KmdManager-7710/), but there was an error:

Invalid handle (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE).

P.S. The same error is thrown when I tried to load the driver as a service through StartService.

P.S.S. Other drivers loaded properly.

Comment: What is ntstatus code ?

Comment: DbgView don't show anything..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. CreateService / StartService not suitable for KMDF-drivers.